# Simple poset topology question

Tags: calculus, general-topology, algebra-precalculus

What are the open sets on {a,b,c,d} with the poset topology?

The relation is $a\leq b\leq c$ and $a\leq d.$

I know that the sets {x|x<=a} form a basis.

I get a basis is {a,b,c,d}, {b,c}, {c}, {d}

So the open sets are {a,b,c,d}, {b,c}, {c}, {d}, {c,d}, {b,c,d}, empty set.

Is this correct?

Comment: In a poset, the ordering relation is transitive, right? So $\{x:x\le c\}=\{a,b,c\}?$ So $\{a,b,c\}$ is a (basic) open set?

Comment: @bof yeah I think I got a bit confused.